# my javafx project doesn't read data from the database

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, javafx

So i created a database table in intellij and i made a javafx project and it's connected to my server(localhost)
now i'm getting errors here

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM IntellijDB.dbo.Employee WHERE username = ? and passcode = ?";
```

it says I'm unable to access the table

this is the method

```
public boolean isLogin(String user,String pass) throws SQLException
{
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null ;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM IntellijDB.dbo.Employee WHERE username = ? and passcode = ?";
    try
    {
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,user);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,pass);

        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
        //TODO: handle exception
    }
    finally {
        preparedStatement.close();
        resultSet.close();
    }
}
```

and the other error here

```
if (loginModel.isLogin(userAction.getText(), passAction.getText()))
```

and this line too

```
resultSet.close();
```

and I guess they are related and i don't know how to fix this
this is the other code

```
@FXML
public void Login(ActionEvent event) {
    try {


        if (loginModel.isLogin(userAction.getText(), passAction.getText())) {
            isConnected.setText("Username & password is correct");
        }
        else
        {
            isConnected.setText("Check your username or password");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        isConnected.setText("Check your username or password");
        //TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just ignore an exception when you're debugging, like you do here: `catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
        /*TODO: handle exception*/
    }` Always print/log the exception since it contains valuable information about the problem. From the description of the error there's almost certainly something wrong with the table name or the column names in the query (`preparedStatement.executeQuery()` seems to throw an exception).

Comment: i found my issue actually i stored my values for username and password in TEXT and that wasn't compatible with String ...... so i changed it to varchar